# Is it possible to convert a python function into a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-languages

I am new to Python coming from C++ background and this is the first time I am seeing a language which contains nothing but objects. I have just learned that class and functions are also just objects. So, is there a way to convert the following function to a class?

```
In [1]: def somefnc(a, b):
...:     return a+b
...:
```

I have first tried assigning the `__call__` variable to `None` to take away the "callable nature" from the function. But as you can see, **the `__call__` was successfully replaced by `None` but this didn't cause the function to stop adding numbers when called, though, `somefnc.__call__(1,3)` was working before assigning `somefnc.__call__` to `None`**

```
In [2]: somefnc.__dict__ 
Out[2]: {}

In [3]: somefnc.__call__
Out[3]: <method-wrapper '__call__' of function object at 0x7f282e8ff7b8>

In [4]: somefnc.__call__ = None

In [5]: x = somefnc(1, 2)

In [6]: print(x)
3

In [7]: somefnc.__call__

In [8]: print(somefnc.__call__(1, 2))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
ipython-input-8-407663da97ca     
in <module>()
----> 1 print(somefnc.__call__(1, 2))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

In [9]: print (somefnc(1,2))
3

In [10]:
```

**I am not doing this for developing purpose here,** so claiming this to be a bad practice will not make any sense. I am just trying to understand Python very well. Of course, for development purpose, I could rather create a class than to convert a function to one!

After robbing the function off its ability to add two numbers, I am thinking of assigning a valid function to the attribute `somefnc.__init__` and some members by modifying `somefun.__dict__`, to convert it to a class.

Comment: What does this have to do with the function being 'a class'?

Comment: Weird. I think you're trying to hack that poor defenseless function object into a class _instance_ rather than a class, per se, since a class is actually a type, and an instance of a given class is an object of that type. (And yes, types are objects too).

Comment: You need to patch methods like that on the *class*, not the *instance*. Fortunately, as it would break pretty much everything to let you do that (*all* functions would become un-callable), `type(somefnc).__call__ = None` leads to `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'function'`. If you want to patch built-ins, see [forbidden fruit](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit), but tread carefully...

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, I guess that's what I am trying to do. To understand this language better. But assigning None to __call__ does not rob the ability of the function to add two numbers. Why is that?

Comment: Since your goal is "to understand Python very well" one thing you'll need to thoroughly understand (if you don't already) is that [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables). For a deeper discussion on that topic see [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the resources !!

Comment: By the way, a python function *is* a class. More precisely, a type.

Comment: @user312016, that's is the precise reason why I am trying to get a function to behave like a class! But for some reason, it is not possible.

Comment: @HelloWorld But a function behaves like a class since a function *is* a class

Comment: @user312016 I tried assigning `somefnc.__call__ = None`. But still, the call to the function `somefnc(1, 3)` works. Once, I make sure `somefnc(1,3)` doesn't work, I could try something like, `somefnc.__init__ = initialize`, to get it to behave like a class.

Comment: You got it right.  In Python, "everything is an object."

Comment: This is an unusual but interesting approach to groking function, but instead of hacking functions as classes, why not simply implement a class?  Classes are sort of built for customization where you can overload the special methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python functions are instances of the `function` class. So I'll give you a general answer about any class and instance.

```
In [10]: class Test:
    ...:     def __getitem__(self, i):
    ...:         return i
    ...:     

In [11]: t = Test()

In [12]: t[0]
Out[12]: 0

In [13]: t.__getitem__(0)
Out[13]: 0

In [14]: t.__getitem__ = None

In [15]: t[0]
Out[15]: 0

In [16]: t.__getitem__(0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-c72f91d2bfbc> in <module>()
----> 1 t.__getitem__(0)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

In Python all special methods (the ones with double underscores in the prefix and the postfix) are accessed from the class when triggered via operators, not from the instance.

```
In [17]: class Test2:
    ...:     def test(self, i):
    ...:         return i
    ...:     

In [18]: t = Test2()

In [19]: t.test(1)
Out[19]: 1

In [20]: t.test = None

In [20]: t.test(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-261b43cb55fe> in <module>()
----> 1 t.test(1)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

All methods are accessed via the instance first, when accessed by name. The difference is due to different search mechanics. When you access a method/attribute by name, you invoke `__getattribute__` which will first search in the instance's namespace by default. When you trigger a method via operators, `__getattribute__` is not invoked. You can see it in the disassembly.

```
In [22] import dis

In [23]: def test():
    ...:     return Test()[0]
    ...:     

In [24]: dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Test)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR
             10 RETURN_VALUE

In [25]: def test2():
    ...:     return Test().__getitem__(0)
    ...: 

In [26]: dis.dis(test2)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Test)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__getitem__)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, there is no `LOAD_ATTR` in the first case. The `[]` operator is assembled as a special virtual-machine instruction `BINARY_SUBSCR`.

Comment: Thanks! So the function actually refers its class  for the `__call__` method and not the instance it has within itself!

Comment: @HelloWorld I updated the answer to explain it.

Comment: Great answer @Eli Kovigo